# Load js plugin using Require.js after Marionette module is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Im new with Marionette and Requirejs. I started to change my old code structure (backbone) to Marionette. Using Requirejs I changed my old list of scripts needed in my initial html page to Requirejs sintax. Until then is fine, the scripts are loaded in every module where I ask. For example:

```
define(['App', 'dhController', 'menu', 'gridmenu', 'menubar', 'sidebar', 'asPieProgress'], function(app) {
  app.module('dh.Views', function (Views, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _)   {

  ....other stuff...
        //----- REQUESTS -----

        // Dashboard Request Item View
        // -------------------
        //
        // Display an individual request panel

        Views.ERequest = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            tagName: 'div',
            template: '#template-request', **<-- In this template is the pluging needed**

            ui: {
                pieChart: '.pie-progress-level'
            },

            onRender: function () {
                this.ui.pieChart.asPieProgress("go", 50);
            }
        });

        // Dashboard Request Collection View
        // -------------------
        //
        // Display a list of requests

        Views.ERequests = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
            tagName: 'ul',
            childView: Views.ERequest,

            initialize: function () {
                this.render();
            },

            ui: {}
        });
});
```

The problem is: I understand that the page must be loaded in order to use these plugin (in this case is jquery-asPieProgress). So, how could I load those scripts files AFTER the whole page is rendered.. because if I use ***define([..], function(..){});*** or ***require(..)***. As I have said, the scripts are loaded before and they don't do anything.

Hope it's clear. Thanks

**SOLUTION**

Well I guess it depends on how you structure your app. In my case, I have a module with the typical router logic inside. Well, in the same file I added (at the end) a function with a timeout of 100 and the I required the elements I need.

```
var app = require('App');
app.module('CRouter', function (CRouter, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) 
{ ... router logic ...});

    /**
     * Load all the files needed in template
     */
    setTimeout(function() {
        require(['menu', 'menubar', 'sidebar', 'gridmenu', 'configcolors', 'configtour', 'breakpoint', 'asScrollable'],
            function() { ... run whatever which needs these libs ... }
        );
    }, 100);
```

You can see and clear example here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#afterload

Comment: Did you try using a shim? See: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: I already thought about it.. but that would be fine for those scripts which have dependencies... for one: backbone (deps:[underscore]) or marionette (with backbone) or in my case that Im using a ui template site:{deps:[core]}. My problem is that I need to render everything before the plugin aspieprogress.js runs so it can get the elements in the page.. no?

Comment: Here's the [3 Stages Of A Backbone Applications Startup](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/06/3-stages-of-a-backbone-applications-startup/) from the Marionette author. It's a 4-year-old post though so the latest version is probably different.

Comment: If you need something to run after the page is rendered, would you find success with the View dom:refresh event?

http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event

The docs state: 
"This event / callback is useful for DOM-dependent UI plugins such as
jQueryUI or KendoUI."

Comment: Are you looking for  [DOM Ready](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload)?